# The sample projects mentioned in Android Developer Official website cannot be found

Tags: android, android-studio

I have been reading the Android official [Canvas & Drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#on-view) document, there it mentioned a sample project :

```
For a sample application, see the Snake game, in the SDK samples folder: <your-sdk-directory>/samples/Snake/.
```

I opened my Android Studio 1.0.1, chose **File --> Import Sample ...** , but I can not find the sample project from the window.

In the document, it also mentioned another sample project:

```
For a sample application, see the Lunar Lander game, in the SDK samples folder: <your-sdk-directory>/samples/LunarLander/
```

I am not able to find it either. Why the document mentioned samples are not available in Android Studio "**Import samples...**" option?

(I opened my SDK manager double checked that I have installed all the samples from API 15 to API 22.)

Comment: hi can you see the source code under your <your-sdk-directory>/samples/LunarLander/ directory. I think you need to download the sample with the help of android SDK Mananger

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the above two samples under `<android-sdk>/samples/android-17/`. It would be more convenient if the Android document could mention which **API version** contains the samples, hope Google could improve its document for this.

Besides, the samples are in `android-17/` folder, and they are Eclipse projects not Android Studio projects, I guess that might be the reason why they are not shown in Android Studio **Import Sample ...** window.

But still it is weird that the Android Studio **Import Sample ...** window doesn't provide API level selection, though different API level samples are different. I hope all these could be improved.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Now I just found out that you can find those "old" examples also in the folder *legacy* of your last sdk version.